# Regex for old readme

Tags: regex

I have an old readme text file. And I'm trying to get the text from certain sections.
The sections are

```
--thing1 thing2-- 
stuff
-- thing1 thing2--
more stuff
```

I'm looking for a regex snippet that will return the stuff from that section where thing1 equals "Beta".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<=^--Beta \w+--$).*?(?=^--)
```

Set dot to match line breaks.

Answer (score 1):

```
my %sections =~ m/--[ ]*(\w+[ ]+\w+)[ ]*--(.*?)/g;
print $sections{$_} for grep { m/\A Beta \b / } keys %section;
```